# Can I configure IntelliJ Idea to recognize custom code folding regions designation?

Tags: intellij-idea, region, folding, code-folding, code-regions

I like c# `#region...#endregion` facility a lot (some people say that's a bad habit but let's not discuss that). I miss it a lot when coding other languages. The obvious way to "add" it to other languages is to use special-formed comments the editor would understand. I've managed to set up `Kate` to support `//#region...//#endregion` for Java/Scala code, alike feature is not a problem to achieve with `NetBeans` ([here](http://stoken-tips-and-tricks.blogspot.com/2007/03/howto-use-netbeans-editor-tags.html) is how). Can I do this with IntelliJ Idea 11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [feature is planned](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-80636) for IDEA 11.1 that will be released in late Q1, 2012:

> IntelliJ IDEA 11.1 will support custom folding using NetBeans and
>   Visual Studio style comments.

Comment: Thhanks. I just hope the feature is going to be implemented the way to be usable with any language (through customization). As for me, I want it for Scala primarily.

Comment: Well, as Idea 11.1 is released, I've just updated to it. And this (as presented here http://goo.gl/XNDEF) just doesn't work. Maybe it works with Java but what I meant was a language-agnostic comment based (almost all the languages have comments, don't they?) feature. I am very disappointed. This is sad. I was waiting for this anxiously...

Comment: Please file a request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA for the language where it doesn't work.

Comment: And doesn't work in GSP (Groovy Server Page) and HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile this feature is implemented in IntelliJ IDEA and described here:
http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/folding-custom-regions-with-line-comments.html

You can define code regions using two styles:

**VisualStudio style**

```
#region Description 
Your code goes here... 
#endregion
```

**NetBeans style**

```
// <editor-fold desc="Description"> 
Your code goes here... 
// </editor-fold>
```

But it is recommended to not mix up the two styles in one file. IntelliJ IDEA will recognize the first folding comment encountered, and will assume this as a style chosen for the code.